# Requiered error prevents Faye server to start in Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, faye

I'm trying to test a notification sistem built with faye gem and running on thin. In my local machine I can make it work but when I try to start faye on my EC2 instance at Amazon I get this error message:

Command:

> rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production

Output:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- faye (LoadError)
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /srv/www/app/releases/201509121806504/faye.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>       from /srv/www/app/releases/201509121806504/faye.ru:in`new'
>       from /srv/www/app/releases/201509121806504/faye.ru:in `<main>'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`eval'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`parse_file'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in`app'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in`start'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
>       from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in`'
>       from /usr/local/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
>       from /usr/local/bin/rackup:23:in`'

In my faye.ru file I have a very simple configuration:

```
require 'faye'
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45) 
run faye_server
```

And I've included thin and faye gems in my gem file. When I start it in my local environment works well in production evironment so I'm probably missing something in the EC2 set-up or may be a problem with rubygems?

Thanks

Comment: Try prepending your command with `bundle exec`, it seems your `faye` gem cannot be found with your current setup.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyShein , bundle exec made it work! The gem is in the gemfile and the server set-up was done with oppsworks. I'm going to make some research about permissions and security groups, may be it has something to do with it.

Comment: Now faye server is running but I'm getting a Connection refused error. Do you know about any tutorial for setting up faye in amazon ec2? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have never used faye before, may be this can help you http://thelazylog.com/running-faye-server-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-with-load-balancer/

Comment: Thanks! that's a great tutorial, I didn't setup the port 9292 so I did it and reboot the instance. But I can't reach the 9292 port from '[myurl].com:9292'  yet. I got a connection resused error. I'm trying to find any tip at the logs but this issue seems to affect faye's log too.

Comment: I've just checked netstat -l and I found that besides the faye server says to be started at localhost:9292 the server is not listening to this port. Do ypu have any idea of what could be going on? Thanks!

Comment: Just did an nmap to 9292 port and it is filtered. Do you know if it should be in that status or open?

Comment: It should be open. Maybe you need to change `localhost` to something else, like your server ip or domain, because `localhost:9292` will listen only for local connections.

Comment: You're right! If I run a nmap inside the server's terminal I get it open. I only get the filtered status nmaping it from outside the server. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your command with `bundle exec`, i.e. `bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production`.